# Sum items from a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Banana] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 126
                )
            [Cherry] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 60
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Cherry] => Array
                (
                    [BIL_RateNonTaxed] => 105
                )
        )
)
```

How can I get something like this:

```
$Banana  = Get all `BIL_RateNonTaxed` for `Banana` = 126
$Cherry  = Get all `BIL_RateNonTaxed` for `Cherry` = 165
```

What I tried before asking you is:

```
$Cherry = implode(',', array_map(function($el){ return $el['Cherry']['BIL_RateTaxed']; }, $datas));

$Banana = implode(',', array_map(function($el){ return $el['Banana']['BIL_RateTaxed']; }, $datas));
```

What's my error ?

Thanks so much for you kind help.

Comment: @Akintunde007, I was a little bit confused in my explanation. Updated.

Comment: After your edit you now have NO `BIL_RateTaxed` in your example array but you are using it in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you expect from the `implode` but just replace it with `array_sum`:

```
$Cherry = array_sum(array_map(function($el) {
                                  return $el['Cherry']['BIL_RateTaxed'];
                              }, $datas));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try summing a nested `array_column`.

```
$fruit = 'Banana';
$rateType = 'BIL_RateNonTaxed';

$banana = array_sum(array_column(array_column($datas, $fruit), $rateType));
```

This gives you a little more flexibility and will just return `0` if you use a fruit or rate type that isn't there.

Comment: My initial thought, then I envisioned the _Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_column()_ comment ;-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver array_column ftw. :) and re: the possible undefined function comment, I mainly answer questions here for my own amusement, so it doesn't matter that much to me if it works for the OP or not.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, for my "own amusement", I just accept an answer that works without potential fatal error. :)

Comment: @popomomo No danger of that fatal error as long as you're using a PHP version that hasn't been EOL for years, but you're as entitled to your amusement as I am to mine. ;) No offense intended by my previous comment, btw. I'm referring to the OP in general, not you specifically.